# Is it possible to submit an iOS update to selected countries?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to submit an iOS app update to selected countries only? The existing app is already published in the App store and is available to all countries. The app update (containing localization changes) is only completed for selected languages supported in the current version, so I was wondering if it is possible to do an early update for selected countries first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update goes to all selected countries. There is no way to keep the current version in one set of countries and the update in another set. If you change the countries of the update, the app will only be available in those countries.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but I couldn't find any actual reference documenting this rule on the portal.

Comment: It's not really a rule, it's just how the store works. BTW - don't forget to accept the answer.